# Frag size in IPV6 Fragmentation

Tags: networking, ipv6, ip-fragmentation

I am trying fragmentation with IPV6.Using scapy to craft packets.
My payload size is 1400 bytes and fragment size chosen is 500 bytes and sending 3 fragments such that last fragment is never sent. I am seeing that scapy is generating fragment with payload size 432 bytes.
Fragment extension header is around 8 bytes.
IPV6 header is 40 bytes.

If we sum it all then frag size is coming upto 480 bytes,whereas i have specified it to be 500 bytes.
How is this calculation done? and how was the frag payload size decided to be 432 bytes?

Comment: My *guess* would be that it also reserves space for the link layer header and the IP layer header, but I'm unable to confirm it at the moment

Comment: Like IPv4, the Fragment Offset is 13 bits, meaning that the payload must be fragmented in 64-bit (eight-byte) chunks. _[RFC 2460, Internet Protocol, Version 6 (IPv6) Specification, Section 4.5  Fragment Header](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2460.html#section-4.5) explains exactly how the fragmentation works. There are non-fragmentable parts of the packet, and the fragmentable parts must be fragmented on 64-bit boundaries. That will usually result in fragments smaller than the maximum fragment size you specify.